# Is there a ring whose total ring of fractions is not a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I am trying to come up with an example of a ring whose total quotient ring is not a field. I know that if $R$ is a domain, then every total quotient ring has to be a field, however in the general case I feel like there should be a counterexample.

Comment: How about the integers modulo $n$?

Comment: What is a “total” quotient?

Comment: My notes mention it as a total quotient ring, but I don't see where in the definition the word 'total' is important. Perhaps this is just a convention and it's what people mean by 'quotient ring'. Wikipedia has two different entries for 'total quotient ring': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions

And a quotient ring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring

I am trying to see the difference rn.

Comment: The field of fractions is a very different thing.

Comment: @Randall yeah... I'm confused because my notes say 'total field of fractions', then wikipedia also mentions this as the 'total quotient ring' so I assumed this is the same. And then there's an entry on 'quotient rings' that may be unrelated further confusing me. I will change my phrasing to 'total ring of fractions' as is defined in my notes.

Comment: If $R$ is not a domain, then its total ring of fractions will contain $R$ as a subring, and therefore not be a field.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments; the total ring of fractions of a ring $R$ is a ring containing $R$ as a subring. So if $R$ is not a domain then its total ring of fractions is not a field.

The smallest example of such a ring is $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$. It is not a domain, and it is its own total ring of fractions, which is clearly not a field.